# Update a thing in aws iot

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I am working on connecting to `aws-iot` using java. I created a `thing[supermario]` in `aws-iot` with two attributes`["state": "false", "model":"name"]`

The thing is created successfully with the name supermario and the attributes that I gave and I was able to view that in the `aws` console. I did this by initializing the AWSIotClient and using the class CreateThingRequest. Now I want to update this thing through java. Can I update the thing by `thingname` or should I have to delete the thing and create it? I saw in some code that the existing thing was deleted and then created. How can I update an attribute of this thing using Java?

This is how I created the thing.

```
AWSIotClient awsIotClient = this.initClient();
        CreateThingRequest createRequest = new CreateThingRequest();
        createRequest.setThingName(device.getDeviceId());
        AttributePayload attributePayload = new AttributePayload();
        attributePayload.addAttributesEntry("model", device.getModel());
        attributePayload.addAttributesEntry("state","false");
        createRequest.setAttributePayload(attributePayload);
```

Answer (score 0):

[UpdateThing API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_UpdateThing.html) will update attributes on a Thing.